# Adding photo upload to an iPhone App that's mostly HTML5/JS

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm working on an iPhone App that's HTML5/JS displayed in a single UI Webview. I'd like to add photo upload capabilities, and I'm wondering what the best approach would be to extend the iPhone app with the necessary classes to pick a photo and upload via an API.  I'd also like to trigger the display of the photo picker via JS if that's possible.

I know it's possible to use a framework like PhoneGap to do this, but I don't want to migrate the whole app to a new framework yet.  Also, sorry for the "how to" type question - I normally ask about specific problems after I've exhausted my efforts, but I'm pretty new to Objective C, so I'd appreciate some guidance, even if it's just a simple design explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image picker (UIImagePicker) is fairly straightforward to work with: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

and for an API, are you sending it to an existing system? or creating your own. You just need to craft an NSMutableURLRequest with POSTED data in a multi-part format, and then handle the image portion appropriately in your server.

this might help: [upload image from iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481859/upload-image-from-iphone-application)

Comment: Yeah, will be sending the image to an existing API as part of an http POST.  Thanks a lot for the pointers.

Comment: One more thing...any recommendations on how to trigger the display of the image picker via javascript?